# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a project based in Spring Web model-view-controller (MVC) framework. The version of the Spring Web model-view-controller (MVC) framework is 3.2.8 deployed on a WebLogic Server Version: 12.1.2.0.0

I have this error loading 1 JSP

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function

This is everything I load and I checked 1 by 1 and all of them are loaded

```html
<link href="/tdk/styles/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/tdk/styles/admin.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/tdk/styles/jquery.dataTables.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/tdk/styles/dataTables.bootstrap.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/tdk/styles/slides.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="/tdk/scripts/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/tdk/scripts/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/tdk/scripts/jquery.dataTables.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/tdk/scripts/dataTables.bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    var selected = [];
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
      "dom": '<"top">rt<"bottom"lp><"clear">',
      "autoWidth": false,
      "paging": false,
      "scrollX": false,
      "scrollY": 300,
      "scrollCollapse": true,
      "rowCallback": function(row, data) {
        if ($.inArray(data.DT_RowId, selected) !== -1) {
          $(row).addClass('selected');
        }
      },
      "columnDefs": [{
        "targets": 'nosort',
        "orderable": false
      }, ]
    });
    $('#example tbody').on('click', 'input', function() {
      $(this).closest("tr").toggleClass('selected');

      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        var theNameOfSelectedProduct = $(this).closest("tr").find("td.productname").text();
        $('#selecteddevices').val($('#selecteddevices').val() + " " + theNameOfSelectedProduct);
        $('#actions4devices button').removeAttr("disabled");
      } else {
        var theNameOfSelectedProduct = $(this).closest("tr").find("td.productname").text();
        $('#selecteddevices').val($('#selecteddevices').val().replace(theNameOfSelectedProduct, ""));
        if ($('#selecteddevices').val().trim().length == 0) {
          $('#actions4devices button').not('.pull-right').attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }
      }
    });
    $('#refusedevicesButtonId').on('click', function() {
      $('#theRefuseFile').show();
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Where in relation to the jQuery UI script load is the script that calls `.tooltip` loading?

Comment: no need to load jquery-ui twice

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Can we see where you're using `$.tooltip()` ? It's possible that it occurs somewhere before the jQuery UI embed line. So try re-arranging your script includes so jQuery is first, jQuery UI is second, then along through the rest.

```
<script src="/tdk/scripts/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="/tdk/scripts/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/tdk/scripts/jquery.dataTables.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/tdk/scripts/dataTables.bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Hard to know without seeing your full code and knowing which files contains your calls to `$.toolTip()`.

One other quick attempt would be to substitute `jQuery` for `$` where you're using, i.e.:

`$(".tips").toolTip()`

would become:

`jQuery(".tips").toolTip()`

Comment: If jQuery was the issue the error would be `$ is undefined`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes, but not jQuery UI gone missing (nvm I see now what you're saying re: 2nd part of answer)

Comment: Actually I think that is it. Bootstrap.js tries to use .Tooltip. jQuery needs to exist first so load jQuery, then jQuery UI, then bootstrap

Comment: jQuery UI also has .tooltip() which may be the problem https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/

Comment: This saved me..Worked well in sorting issue

Answer (score 6):

Be aware that [jquery-ui](https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/) has its own .tooltip() function and [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips) does too.

Try to reorder your js files like

```
<script src="/tdk/scripts/jquery.min.js"              type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- Jquery - ui right after-->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="/tdk/scripts/bootstrap.js"                 type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/tdk/scripts/jquery.dataTables.js"         type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/tdk/scripts/dataTables.bootstrap.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: If you're using Bootstrap's tooltip() function, you may wish to build your own flavor of jQuery UI excluding tooltip() but keeping the bits you do need.

Comment: As @PatrickMoore recommends, you may download a new dist without tooltip(). You can do it here https://jqueryui.com/download/.

Comment: That wouldn't cause `is not a function` error. It would just call the wrong function.

Comment: @Chloe  I do not know why the downvote, if it can be a valid answer for this question.

Answer (score 4):

It's probably due to the version of jQuery. At least it was me and I solved this problem like this. I was using jQuery 3.3.1. The problem was solved when I changed the django to 1.10.3. Add this,

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js

It needs work.

Comment: Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post;](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Comment: Oh god this has caused me so much headache. Why is this an issue!?!?! Thank you for this comment.

Answer (score 1):

Because `jQuery 3.5.1` is getting larger it takes more time to load, in addition to the ordering of the JavaScript files, mentioned in many answers to this question, the way to go in addition to fixing the order which by the way does not always work, for `Bootstrap tooltip option`, a work around is to use a timeout based on `jQuery` loading time, example:

```
setTimeout(function () {
        $("[title]").tooltip({
            container: "body",
            placement: "top",
            delay: { show: 240, hide: 60 }
        });

        $("[title]").on("click", function () {
            $(this).tooltip("hide");
        });
    }, 545*1.33); // 545ms timing to load jQuery.js + network estimated delay
```

Comment: This was the answer in my case.  I had this bug and tried the suggestions above.  It still occurred but I could not get it to repeat reliably.  There was actually a correlation with my connection speed.  Implementing setTimeout solved it.

Answer (score 1):

`tooltip()` was only added to jQuery UI in jQuery UI version 1.9.  Proof...

> version added: 1.9 (Source: **[API.jQueryUI.com: Tooltip Widget](https://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/)**.)

If you don't have a version of jQuery UI at version 1.9 or higher, you'll get the error: `tooltip() is not a function()`.

Answer (score -1):

To solve this you'll have to add to your gemfile:

```
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-themes'
```

Then you won't have the problem that jquery-ui isn't loading anymore Another solution is to require("bootstrap") in application.js seemingly in addition to import("bootstrap") and you have install jquery and bootstrap with yarn too I think this all pretty crazy